# Github ate my source code (my commit is gone)

Tags: github, github-for-mac

Late yesterday I finished up a day's worth of work and went to github and commited, then hit the sync button. I briefly saw a message on the screen saying something about needing to fix merge conflicts, but the message was self-dismissed before I could read it completely.

My outstanding commit disappeared, so I figured all was well. This morning I started work again and ALL the new code that I did had been reverted to the prior commit from two days before. There is no mention of any of the changes I had made nor of the commit I did just before finishing up my work day... they are just gone.

Any suggestions on recovery?

**UPDATE**

For what it's worth, I was browsing the log files in my git folder and I see my commit:

```
37c661799950211c713630301cf8cbe609de6c59 f94366329fa93cec529b83b34a607449725f5270 [user info removed] 1360710557 -0700  commit: Shout page
f94366329fa93cec529b83b34a607449725f5270 b588ed19e77ef55611a4a82896c5ef2c26f3e4cd [user info removed] 1360710567 -0700  checkout: moving from master to     b588ed19e77ef55611a4a82896c5ef2c26f3e4cd^0
b588ed19e77ef55611a4a82896c5ef2c26f3e4cd b588ed19e77ef55611a4a82896c5ef2c26f3e4cd [user info removed] 1360710576 -0700  rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
```

Comment: does gitk show a difference between which commit the remote central repo is on and where your local repo is pointing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `git reflog` to find the hash of the lost commit. You can then either use `git cherry-pick`, `git merge` or `git reset --hard` (depending on what it is you want to do with the lost history) to recover. If you need to see diffs in order to identify your commit, use `git reflog -p`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did a local commit first, don't you? Check your local branch first:

```
git log --oneline
```

Not sure what you did, but if there was a merge conflict while pushing, you should still have your changes locally.

Comment: This is using the github UI for mac. I did the commit local, then pushed it (using the Sync button). git log shows the last commit being the one I got reverted back to (i.e, there is no mention of mine in there)

Comment: So open the github shell and check what the command above returns. Afterwards I can extend my answer to help you get your changes back. A failed push will not result in data loss if you have a local commit!

Comment: Not sure where the github shell is; but I've got the normal git command-line tools already installed. I went to my local repo and did git log command and the latest commit showing is from two days ago (not the one I commited late yesterday)

Comment: In that case, go with the answer suggested by @Michael Wild and use git reflog to figure out the ID of your lost comment. Afterwards, create a new branch and cherry-pick this commit from it.